# Night time potty training for four years old

Tags: potty-training, night-time

Our 4 years old son is very good at using toilet during the day, but he still wets his nappy more often than not (he wears nappies only for the night). He doesn't seem to be bothered about this at all. What is the best way to train him not to use the nappy during the night? And when is the best time to do it?

Comment: Have you tried going without the diaper/nappy to see what happens? What things have you tried to train him at night? If you provide more details we can give you some fresh ideas and not waste your time suggesting things you've already tried.

Comment: We waited until our son had dry pullups most nights, he was 4.5. He didn't want to let the pullups go during the night, so we had to tell him that by 5 there was no more pullups. By then he really didn't need them.
My brother took their 4 year old and put her on the potty when they went to bed a couple of hours after her. He said she barely woke up.

Answer (score 1):

Kids develop at a wide range of rates. Your son may not have the bladder capacity to go an entire night without peeing. I also wouldn't assume he is waking up to pee. I have 4 kids and some took longer than others to wake up dry consistently. Especially if you allow him to have fruit juices or anything with sugar later in the day. They can contribute to increased urination.

Also, noticed "nappy" and if I didn't have a wife who was South African, I wouldn't know what that was (American problems). They are called diapers almost exclusively over here despite the fact the rest of the English speaking world calls them "napkins", "nappys" or "nap naps".

Answer (score 1):

He's not bothered, because he has no concept that wearing nappies is not a normal thing. He has been doing it all his life.

A couple of things you could try.

1. Avoid giving him drinks just before bed. Try instead to encourage him to drink more water earlier in the afternoon.
2. Get him up to go to the toilet an hour or so after he goes to sleep. This is a bit disruptive, but it may be possible to do it without him waking up fully. If you keep this up for a while, he might start to do it on his own.

The aim is just to keep his nappy dry for a few weeks or a month, and hopefully it will become a habit.

Comment: I use #2 with my 2 1/2 year old son. I take him to the bathroom about 2 hours after he falls asleep. It was difficult at first, but now he doesn't even wake up for it.